# How can I handle this error?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I'm a new developer with c#, I created a c# project and I need to access the SQL database to perform the SELECT statement

and I got this error in this figure

[image]

My connection statement is correct, so what's wrong with it ?!

I tried the mentioned solutions and I got this error

[image]

does anyone know how to handle it ?!

Comment: try{you.handle(this.Error);} catch(exc){you.send(exc,stackOverflow)} :)

Comment: The error tells you what to do, surely?!

Comment: This error can be because of multiple reasons , wrong database name , firewall etc. However follow this link it may help you - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8cdc71eb-6929-4ae8-a5a8-c1f461bd61b4/provider-sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified?forum=sqlexpress

Comment: @F505 One advice though try to put your connection string in your web config .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is telling you what to do, **your connection is not open yet**. Open it like:

```
con.Open();
```

Before executing your command.

Couple of things for your code, Use parameterized query, this will save you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), also use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) statement which will ensure disposal of connection object.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmpName FROM Employee WHERE EmpID=@EmpID", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", id.Text);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    //..... your rest of the code
}
```

EDIT:

For your edited part of question, you are having issue with your SQL Server not allowing remote connection. You have to enable it.

See: [How to enable remote connections in SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Comment: @F505, now your new issue is a separate one, your SQL Connection doesn't allow remote connection, check the edited part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Reader needs open connection

Put `con.Open()` before executing reader

```
SqlCommand cmd = newSqlCommand("SELECT EmpName from Employee where EmpID =" +id.Text,con);
con.open(); //Open connection
SqlReader Read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (Read.Read())
{
 Position =Read[0].tostring();
}
read.close();
con.close();//Close connection after reader finishes reading
con.Dispose();
```

Comment: Your string query is not adding value of `id.Text`, instead it is adding the text, also consider using parameters and `using`, since `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` implements `IDisposable`

Comment: @Habib Well i also prefer parameterized query, however thanks for pointing out !